# Return only certain subclasses from union subclass

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this situation in NHibernate. I've got a base concrete class (Animal), and two union subclasses (Dog and Cat).

I want a query that filters the subclasses i don't want, something like this

```
                var result = session.CreateCriteria<Animal>()
                                // .Add(NotOfType(Cat))
                                .List<Animal>();
```

Because Animal is a concrete class, there is a table for this, and I want to retrieve all animals except Cat(including "generic" Animals and Dogs)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each entity has special property called `class`.

```
var result = session.CreateCriteria<Animal>()
                    .Add(Expression.Not( Expression.Eq("class", typeof(Cat)))
                    .List<Animal>();
```

or in HQL

```
from Animal a where a.class != 'Cat'
```